# JSON disk / memory size ratio

Tags: json, node.js, memory

I've written my json structure in such a way that the file (after taking a month worth of measurements) is still only around 100 mb when stored on disk. However the file now is around 20mb but I see that the memory my script needs is around 200/300 mb. Obviously the script and compiler needs memory but is it true that loading json txt into memory as actual json increases memory roughly 8 fold to the size of the txt file (measured using `process.memoryUsage()`)?. I need the data to constantly stay in memory as other functions require the data upon a user request. I only save it to a file as a backup. However at this rate my server is not going to be able to handle the script.

Can anyone confirm that this is indeed the case? And if so, how would you suggest I could reduce memory load?

Comment: Just as a side note, I used to fetch JSON API from league of legends server data into my Java program and it consumed lot of memory (about 100MB, for just few small files). JSON is bad idea for big pieces of data, it's good for APIS and stuff, but not as a storage. Anyway, think about stuff as typed arrays in Javascript. It requires to think more about design, since you can't resize them, but uses less memory and CPU upon operation.

Comment: @Tomáš Zato I'm doing something similar. How did you eventually do this? Did you use some kind of database system?

Comment: No, I created classes with only the properties I needed, I gave them a `fromJson` method where they loaded JSON data, then I dropped the JSON off memory. But keep in mind that javascript memory, unlike Java memory, looks pretty much like JSON. But you could probably check if you really need ALL the data, and database doesn't sound so stupid unless you need to be lightning fast. If you do, buy more RAM.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you ever solve this? Why is in-memory json so much bigger than on-file json? Is there a more efficient way to store it in memory?

Comment: Clarification: I'm declaring the "json" in a js file so I guess it is more correct to call it a "javascript object" which is somehow way bigger in memory than on file. I'm assuming you had the same situation?

Answer (score 0):

Json file size representation is the actual numbers of bytes it is currently using.

The RAM will vary. Depending on the language used, and the variable type.
[As per documentation](http://www.json.org/), the language will use the value type size when allocating the RAM.

> {"aNumber":1}

uses `1` byte in a file, but uses `8` bytes (in Java) when allocated in memory

To simplify, you can estimate that RAM usage will be file size multiplied by the largest type. So, Yes, file size times eight is a good estimate.

#### Edit:

Also, remember that variable names (strings) will occupy file size, and ram pointers will use more than that

#### Edit 2:

`And if so, how would you suggest I could reduce memory load?`

We could use more information on your system or need. but roughly, the more information segregation the better.

I have a system with 3200 sensors, and a expectancy of 7000 total. For my system, I have each "file output" with a hundred registries each, and each registry has up to 10 fields. This means usually a ~30kb file, that uses up to 300kb RAM each, then I can have a distributed service read one, work on that file, and re-output it where as needed.

If you can, then  use multiple files with a low ammount of data each time, and once one has been processed, move to the next one

Comment: `{"aNumber":1}` uses one byte? I don't think so. Could you explain how did you come to this, as well as the `8` bytes for Java?

Comment: Create a new file. Writte "1" inside, save file. Right click file, properties, check file size and file used in disk. Usually 1byte written, and 4 kb used in disk... For the java part is trickier, but if you search on google, in Java, a double uses 8 bytes, an int uses 4, and a char 2, so the `TYPE` of the variable is the important figure to check upon

Comment: Thanks, I might just split it up. Now it is a collection of roughly 33.000 dictionaries. How would you suggest I save the data? Serialize it?

Comment: @Bonatti But the file contains `{"aNumber":1}`. And so does Java memory. Are we both talking about JSON?

Comment: @TomášZato No. What I meant was, the value of a number uses chars to represent them. But the number itself will use more than that. At the same time, the name of the variable uses more chars (usually), and in memory will be pointers, that will use fewer bytes.... so, to simplify, you can estimate that (for doubles, integers and other basic variables), the file size times eight is a good approach to maximum RAM used.

Comment: @SecondLemon Is there any rule to the segregation? For instance, my data is relative to the day they happened, so, they are split in folders by: Year, Month, Day, Hour, Region, ID of machine.... Having over a thousand files in a folder can cause performance issues. I suggest separating in files in a way that they can be contained by the server RAM (perhaps each file with up to 2 MB, and up to 600 files per folder

Comment: @Bonatti Imagine it as a price watcher. There are items, roughly 22000, and I measure price/unit information every 2 hours (so yes the data is linked to a time frame). To reduce the json load I already have taken out as much as characters as possible and make it very condense. I also summarize data of measurements older than 7 days per day. The problem I have eventually is that I would like users to make requests that analyzes all the data of all the items. Thus I am forced to keep it in memory right?

Comment: `I am forced to keep it in memory right? ` Not really, you could batch the search for indexes.... Say, you want the cheapest `X` product, then read a couple files (or hundreds of them), search what you asked, then output just that info... How is the data archived, processed and served? For instance, in my ambient, I allowed for a couple of queries... by date, by highest  value, by thresholds, etc... When you stated that the user "analyzes" the data, what is he searching for? If you own the web server system, you can particionate the output, then only serve what is requested

Comment: I have a formula that applies to the data and detects a down trend (within the users input timeframe). That will be the main output. However I thought I might just pre-process the data myself with some useful fixed timeframes. That should reduce load a lot already. 

But is splitting up the data useful? If two users ask for a request with different conditions a lot of data will be in memory in duplicate right? Not sure if keeping it all in memory actually solves this but would love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: `If two users ask for a request with different conditions a lot of data will be in memory in duplicate` Depends, if your server has ram to spare, and never does memory pagination, than true, keeping everything in memory will be your best and fastest approach. If for instance you have `4 GB RAM` in server, that would offer a limit of `512 MB HD`... if you think you will never reach that aproximated limit, than load everything up... however, note that just the files you are using are allocating all that memory. If you are just searching 1 value... that is wasted resources (energy, time, etc).